# Android activity state

Tags: android, android-activity

In Android applications, is it possible to be notified when the activity is paused 
but without using onDestroy method in the activity class.

In other words, I want the operations to be outside the main class.

Comment: U can call a function which is in outside main class from onPause()..

Comment: as i understtod, u dont want to use onDestroy(), onPause() or obStop() methods correct ?

Comment: can you explain a little more about the problem?  do you to monitor `ActivityLifecycle` of an activity that is not part of your application?

Comment: yes I want to monitor it from outside the activity
because i'm developing a library

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onPause()` method of [Activity life cycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html):

[image]

Comment: How to use it outside the main activity (I don't want to use it in the main activity)

Comment: You can have a variable in outside and main Activity and set that inside OnPause of MainActivity. Or simply call a function of the outer class.

Answer (score -1):

just override onPause method.

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
    }
```

When activity is going to pause. it will call this method.

Comment: what is problem in this ans?

Comment: The problem is this is done in the main activity class .. i want to make it outside